# Hive Query: Exhaustive Search

Tags: sql, hive, mathematical-optimization

I have this table in below schema...

```
      Pos1 Pos2 Pos3
KW1    $1   $2   $3
KW2    $4   $5   $6
KW3    $7   $8   $9
```

I need the cost of all possible combination. 
Say when keyword `KW1` appears in position 1 (`Pos1`) the cost associated is `$1`.

Hence one such combination would be `Comb1=$1+$4+$7` Another possible combination would be `Comb2=$1+$5+$7`. Only constraint is for each keyword only one position can be selected. 
Is it possible to do this search using Hive Query? Looking for any pointers.

**Objective:** Find the combination which would result to meet the target spend.

Comment: Is it just the three position columns, or are we considering n positions?

Comment: Doesn't your example, `Comb1=$1+$4+$5`, use KW2 in position1 and position2?

Comment: @mdahlman Yes, you are correct i have rectified that. The solution now is 'Comb1=$1+$4+$7' thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @thyme It is not going to be n. There will be a fixed number of columns. For this sample 3 is safe assumption has a hard code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that your problem is the [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), which can be efficiently solved by the [Hungarien method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

If not, you should provide a more detailed explanation.

Comment: True. This can be solved using some optimization technique. However my sample is not very big. I need to get all possible solutions for the above matrix. Let me know what further explanation you require in detail? 
The question here is can something like this be done using HQL?